# Force Universal Links to open in Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links

I have a http link to a page. I want the users to stay in Safari when they click on this link, even if there is an app that has universal links enabled that should intercept it.

This was apparently possible in the past using `target="_top"` in an iframe, but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @BalázsPapp Yes actually, 2 options, but it's quite tricky (and not sure it still works). Option 1: Call a web worker which calls you back to open the link (window.location) Option 2: Bind touchstart and touchend event and open the link on this.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the scenario correctly, you have managed to configure Universal Linking for an app - and you have used the same associated-domains value for the app as is used on your website. Now, when tapping on links to the website, the app always opens.

Well, congratulations on getting Universal Linking working - this is something that many people struggle with!

To achieve the pre-Universal Linking beheavior of having links open the web site instead of opening your app, you will need to break Universal Linking. Fortunately, it seems much easier to break Universal Linking than it is to get it working:

- At the risk of stating the obvious, you can change the link domain used in the app so that it is not the same as the web site.
- Another option would be to turn off Universal Linking for the app in question on a per-device basis. To do this: open the app using a Universal Link and then click on the small button that appears in the upper right-hand corner of the screen - clicking on this button disables Universal Linking for the app on the device. Probably not what you are looking for.
- Finally, you can deploy your links in such a way that Universal Linking will not be triggered. Apple requires that Universal Links be directly tapped on by the end user (see: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26760). You can therefore prevent the app from opening by having users tap on a button or link (a shortened link, for example) that redirects to the website instead of opening it directly. The redirection will prevent the Universal Link from opening the app.